# animate div background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a `<div>`:

```html
<div class="hide1" id="MDive">
    <TABLE WIDTH="1000" BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
```

In this `<div>` I have the complete body of the page.

I also have two classes:

```html
<style>
    .hide1 {
        background: url(bgs/bg_first.png) no-repeat;
    }
    .hide2 {
        background: url(bgs/Picture-12_SOFT.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

I have one image in the body:

```html
<div class="mover">
    <IMG SRC="images/buttons_full_03.png" WIDTH=129 HEIGHT=30 ALT="" border="0">
</div>
```

What I need is: when the cursor comes over the `div.mover`, `div#MDive`'s class changes to `hide2` with an animation.

i.e.: `div#MDive`'s background image changes to the second image with an animation effect

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the the JQUery.Hover event

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover

And then your animate event,

http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.3/Effects

Another top: look into Opacity when changing the background image.

Pino